# Can't install kubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, kubuntu, uefi, 22.04, gigabyte

I have a Gigabyte h610m s2h ddr4 with rtx 3050 graphic card hard drive is 1T M.2 ssd. The computer in question had windows 11 installed. When installing KUbuntu I have tried instructions from [here](https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/how-to-install-ubuntu-22-04-lts.html). With both Automatic Partitioning, and Manual Partitioning.
During the installation setup I had clicked the option to install third party packages, mainly for nvidia drivers. The install completes successfully. When I reboot, the Kubuntu doesn't boot. Instead it just shows the motherboard/bios logo.

I had also tried to install OpenSuse 15.4, and after reboot I can get the working system. So I guess that OpenSuse installer does something right.  However, when I install the NVidia drivers (was following procedure described [here](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:NVIDIA_drivers)), I get the blank screeen after the reboot. My guess is that since nvidia kernel modules are not signed, they can't be loaded. And I don't know how to invoke mokutils. So I'm stuck

My questions:

1. What options do I need to turn on/off in motherboard BIOS? And yes, I have fast boot and secure boot turned off. Do I need something more than that?
2. How do I partition the disk?
3. Which device should I select for boot loader installation? Is it /sda, /sda1 (say this is the EFI partition)

Please help me.

Comment: You may have a corrupt ISO or you may have simply needed to edit the grub menu and add the nomodest option. I suggest you follow these 2 set of instructions and reinstall the Kubuntu that you wanted. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview and https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Comment: I had checked the sha256 signature and everything was fine. Furthermore, I had tried to install Kubuntu with two different usb sticks (one was created with kde app, and another with rufus on windows), and the behaviour was identical. So I guess that the ISO is not corrupted. Regarding the grub menu: I don't get to the grub menu after the installation. Oh, you had pasted the same link for proposed 2 sets of instructions.

Comment: That's the damnest thing. I had turned off fast boot and secure boot in BIOS, installed Kubuntu using automatic partitioning, turned on download updates and installing third party proprietary drivers, and I was left with the system that doesn't boot. Oh, live distro (clicked Try Kubuntu) works flawlesly. I'm almost certain that I'm doing something wrong (i.e. quite positive that it's not ubuntu's fault), but I just can't figure out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had figured out what went wrong.

Well, long story short: for RTX 3050, the solution was **NOT** to install the 520 open kernel driver, but the NVidia's proprietary 520 driver.
[image: NVidia driver]